# Problem when building a maven project in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I m new to Java as well as Maven Build tool and encountered some issues while creating and building a maven project.
IDE: **Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2** 
Jdk version: **java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS** 
Maven version: **Apache Maven 3.9.0**

While following an article on [internet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-maven-project-in-intellij-idea/), which is on the topic - **"How to create a Maven project in Intellij"** I created a maven project and it automatically started building it. Once it was built, it gave me several errors :

```
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
```

[image]

[image]

 
 
Below I have also attached a screenshot of my maven settings, now what am I supposed to do ? 
[image]

**Update 1:** On performing `File -> Invalidate caches` building project gives no error as such but I do get a squiggly line on the maven pane (screenshots attached below)
[image]

Comment: Does the error persist if you click "Reload All Maven Projects" in the right Maven pane at the top? (cyclical arrows button)

Comment: Try "File -> Repaire IDE" and keep following the instruction until you restart your IDE

Comment: I performed both suggestions mentioned above but none of the them worked out for me !!

Comment: Tangential, but that's a decade-old version of maven-site-plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: you are not using maven 3.9.0, but the one you configured in IDEA: 3.8.1 - if you want to change that, you have to change your maven config in IDEA. (But the version shouldn't make the difference here)

Did you "Try to run Maven import with the -U flag" as IDEA suggested to you? I would recommend it. If you try, make sure your internet connection works for that time, you need it at least once, until the plugin has been downloaded to the cache.

If that doesn't work: Try to delete the folder of the dependency in your local maven repository. Default location for the repository is ~/.m2/repository, the plugin should be stored in ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin
(~ is a shortcut for your home folder - from your screenshots I see, the repository is in C:\users\sprud.m2\repository, so you are looking for the folder `C:\users\sprud\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-site-plugin`)

In the maven-site-plugin folder you will find one or more subfolders for the different versions, delete the folder `3.3` and all of its content. In case of doubt, delete the whole folder `maven-site-plugin`. This is only a local cache and can easily be redownloaded.

Then try the build again.

Btw: the most current version of the maven-site-plugin is 3.12.1, the version 3.3 you try to use is nearly 10 years old now. (See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-site-plugin for details) You should try to use a recent version. (Still no reason why the plugin is not found.)

If the solutions above don't work, please have a look into your maven settings.xml file (in `C:\users\sprud\.m2\settings.xml`) There might be some configs for a mirror or plugin repository. Or your `pom.xml` contains a definition of a plugin repository that doesn't contain that plugin.

Comment: how am I supposed to perform  "Maven import with the -U flag" ? like what command should I run in the terminal ?

Comment: In the IDEA window, that message is a link - you can just click it to perform the suggested action

Comment: hey @cyberbrain "Maven import with -U flag" doesn't seems to help in anyway, will try other options u have mentioned

Comment: In the second method of deleting the <folder 3.3> and all of its content inside the folder maven-site-plugin. This partially works (for clear understanding see the screenshot attached in Update 1: section) Why am I still noticing a squiggly line in maven panel even though project has been built without any errors, how to fix it ?

Comment: Is the squiggly line everything that's left? (So the build actually works?) Then try to reload the maven project inside IDEA or restart IDEA - it's a bug that chases me from time to time that IDEA just doesn't recognize changes for updated dependencies.

Comment: thnx for your time !! the squiggly lines also vanished away somehow

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve your problem, feel free to accept it so others (with maybe a similar problem) know that without having to dig through the comments.